# deleting data via datagrid view mySQL Vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

When I click the delete button, the data in the mysqldatabase is deleted but the data in the datagridview is still there. How can I delete the data in the datagridview?

This is my code

```
 cmd.CommandText = "delete from pawn where category = '" & txtCategory.Text & "'"
 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
```

Comment: Rather than having to do it twice, use a DataAdpater and bind the DataGridView to a DataTable.  Then all you have to do is act on the DataSource/DataTable (Update, Insert, Delete) and it will update both.  And never concat SQL - use SQL params.

Answer (score 0):

You can add two buttons, button Delete and button Update to your form.After that you can add the event handler as follows.

```
Private Sub delete_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles delete_btn.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete this row ?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) = DialogResult.Yes Then
        DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index)
       'yourdatadaptername'.Update('yourdatatablename')
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub save_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save_btn.Click
    'yourdatadaptername'.Update('yourdatatablename')

End Sub
```

End Class